# How to add custom syntax annotation to SyntaxNode?

Tags: roslyn

In previous version of Roslyn I could add custom data to `SyntaxNode` with using class derived from `SyntaxAnnotation`. But now `SyntaxAnnotation` is sealed and I can use `SyntaxAnnotation` only with to strings: kind and data. It is not enough for me. I want to build custom CFG from AST and make bidirectional links between CFG and AST nodes.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SyntaxAnnotation` is sealed because your tree may be serialized, and we need to be able to serialize and deserialize the annotations.  If you want to store more info, then store the strings you use for annotations as a key to a dictionary containing the state.

Comment: Thank you Kevin. I am also thinking about dictionary. But this decision seams not so fast and need use some context object (for storing dictionary).

Comment: You would have needed the same context object to store the annotations, wouldn't you?

Comment: At present moment I can't say. Because if I add annotation to every SyntaxNode dictionary will be very huge.

Comment: Sure, but the ConditionalWeakTable of annotations that we would end up creating would be just as big.