# How to escape variable name when using Roslyn C# Syntax Factory?

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn

So I'm using Roslyn SyntaxFactory to generate C# code.

Is there a way for me to escape variable names when generating a variable name using `IdentifierName(string)`?

Requirements:

- It would be nice if Unicode is supported but I suppose ASCII can suffice
- It would be nice if it's reversible
- Always same result for same input ("a" is always "a")
- Unique result for each input ("a?"->"a_" cannot be same as "a!"->"a_")
- Can convert from 1 special character to multiple single ones

Comment: What kind of escaping are you looking for?

Comment: I want a string to be escaped to be usable as a variable name. e.g. `as-.d,as.d,as-.d,` should be usable as a variable name in some form

Comment: depends on why you need it... if you need it only for referencing the variable later, you could just add an [annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260603/how-to-add-custom-syntax-annotation-to-syntaxnode) to the variable declaration, and use a unique variable name instead

Comment: What exactly are you requirements? Does the escaping have to be reversible? Does it have to be unique? (E.g. do `a-` and `a.` have to produce different names?) Does it have to support all Unicode, or is ASCII enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implication from the API docs seems to be that it expects a valid C# identifier here, so Roslyn's not going to provide an escaping mechanism for you. Therefore, it falls to you to define a string transformation such that it achieves what you want.

The way to do this would be to look at how other things already do it. Look at HTML entities, which are always introduced using `&`. They can always be distinguished easily, and there's a way to encode a literal `&` as well so that you don't restrict your renderable character set. Or consider how C# strings allow you to include string delimiters and other special characters in the string through the use of `\`.

You need to pick a character which is valid in C# identifiers to be your 'marker' for a sequence which represents one of the non-identifier characters you want to encode, and a way to allow that character to also be represented. Then make a mapping table for what comes after the marker for each of the encoded characters. If you want to do all of Unicode, the easiest way is probably to just use Unicode codepoint numbers. The resulting identifiers might not be very readable, but maybe that doesn't matter in your use case.

Once you have a suitable system worked out, it should be pretty straightforward to write a string transformation function which implements it.